# Opencv,please tell me how to fix my code

Tags: opencv

I am a beginner and I am learning how to write filters.
I have tried it again and again, but haven't gotten it to work.
Can anyone help me find what is wrong with my code?

```
double alpha;
int beta; 

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{

    Mat image = imread("test.png",1 );
    Mat new_image = Mat::zeros( image.size(), image.type() );

    for( int y = 0; y < image.rows; y++ )
    { 
        for( int x = 0; x < image.cols; x++ )
        {
            for( int ll = -1; ll < 1; ll++ )
            {
                for(int mm=-1; mm<1; mm++)
                {
                    uchar ff1 = image.at<uchar>(x+ll,y+mm);
                    new_image.at<uchar>(x,y) +=ff1;
                }  
            }
        }
    }

    namedWindow("Original Image", 1);
    namedWindow("New Image", 1);

    imshow("Original Image", image);
    imshow("New Image", new_image);

    waitKey();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: "Did not work" is _never_ a sufficient problem description.

Answer (score 1):

You are reading the image as if it was colored (3 channels):

```
Mat image = imread("test.png",1 );
```

but you are treating it as grayscale (1 channel):

```
uchar ff1 = image.at<uchar>(x+ll,y+mm);
```

You can load the image as grayscale with:

```
Mat image = imread("test.png",0 );
```

For all other questions that you will have after reading this answer, please use the **search box** since this topic has been covered numerous times in this forum.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it did not work.

Comment: That was just ONE of the problems with your code :)

Comment: There is something I do not understand.when " new_image.at<uchar>(30,40) = image.at<uchar>(30,40);"is ok but " new_image.at<float>(30,40) = image.at<float>(30,40); would be error". Could you tell me why?

Comment: my head files

#include "stdafx.h" 
 
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>
#include <iostream> 
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;